# Do you know of a NTSC decoder API?

Tags: api, video-processing

I'm looking for an API that I can use to decode a digital sample of an analog signal, encoded according to the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC">NTSC standard. I'm willing to consider both free and commercial options. If I have to, I'll roll the code myself, but I imagine that this code has been written tens or hundreds of times in the past few decades, so I'm hoping there's something out there I can adapt.

Do you know of such an API?

UPDATE: It seems that this code hasn't necessarily been written as many times over as I'd hoped. The solved problem, apparently, is dealing directly with the analog input via particular devices. What I'm looking for is an algorithm that takes as input a direct digital sample of the analog signal (with sufficient resolution to pick up the changes specified in the standard) and returns a video picture, similar to what http://www.physicsforums.com/archive/index.php/t-47403.html">this person wanted and had to build himself.

Comment: How can you have an API to decode an analog signal such as NTSC? Do you mean how to capture NTSC video using a TV Card, or how to decode some kind of storage format like mpeg?

Comment: Did my update answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

I know that some code for this task exists for GNU Radio, though I don't know if it ever got past black&white reception:.

- http://www.nabble.com/NTSC-Receiver-td9123494.html
- http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss-gnuradio@gnu.org/msg01265.html

There is also a GNU Radio [ATSC transceiver](http://www.gnuradio.org/trac/browser/gnuradio/trunk/gr-atsc) that is more complete, though not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Years later ... [This guy](http://codeandlife.com/2012/10/09/composite-video-decoding-theory-and-practice/) has built a decoder in software. Source code is supplied.

Comment: I was looking for a decoder and found this blog post, but the source code was not very helpful since most of the libraries are outdated and I was not able to build an executable.

Comment: So I decided to write a program from scratch in python. I'm releasing the source code on github very soon. Since I don't have raw ntsc signal samples I had to write a ntsc encoder too.

Comment: @DavidBu: It would be interesting to see what you've done. I was researching this topic for retrocomputer emulation, and some great work has been accomplished. This might not be of interest to you, but anyway: https://zellyn.github.io/apple2shader/

Answer (score 0):

The decoding of NTSC into separate R,G,B components with syncing signals has been done in hardware for such a very long time that it is cheap and easy.  There hasn't been any incentive for anyone to try it in software.

Comment: not true. Eric Blossom started the GNU Radio project to do TV decryption, and gr-atsc was one of the side projects that spun off -- also, with highly integrated digital receivers, having an analog component that does the decoding does seem unnecessary.

Answer (score -3):

What you need is the Microsoft DirectShow API. Check this link for API and help: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783323.aspx

I am not sure but Silverlight also probably has the capability you are looking for.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the part of the API that does what I want. Do you have any additional guidance on this? Thanks.

Comment: The DirectShow API has nothing to do with what the original question was about. The question is about a digital representation of the actual NTSC encoded analog signal. The DirectShow API works on a much higher level.