# How do I model UHF TV signal?

Tags: c, model, emulation, television

This may be a strange question, but I would like to programmatically model a UHF TV receiver. Anyone can give me some pointers? I have been looking at the code from emulators, but they are too specific for my purposes right now.

To be more specific: Given some (probably synthesized) UHF analogue signal (in either NTSC or PAL), I would like to decode that signal and show the image on a window, using, say an X11 window.

Comment: In what sense do you want to "model" it? Do you need a mathematical description of the TV signal?

Comment: Oh, well. Now that's something non-trivial.

Comment: NTSC (analog) or ATSC (digital)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: NTSC. In fact, could be NTSC or PAL (both analogue, anyways), once I know what to do, changing the encoding should be trivial (famous last words of programming)

Comment: Then I'd say start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458037/do-you-know-of-a-ntsc-decoder-api

Comment: Modern processors cannot tackle the UHF frequency range.  You always need dedicated hardware anyway to amplify the antenna signal.  Such hardware is readily available, TV tuners for computers are a standard product.  They don't stop at just amplifying, they decode and buffer as well.

Comment: @HansPassant: Oh, I see. I understand what you mean re. the frequency range of procs vs signal. Can't I synthesize the signal downgrading it at a manageable frequency?

Comment: Yes, down-conversion is a universal technique in TV-tuners, 10.7 MHz is the standard. It's done by hardware as well. Still a prety hard frequency to tackle, even for a DSP.  Your inevitable obstacle, if you could call it that, is that tuners already do a lot of the work you want to do by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at xanalogtv from [XScreenSaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/), it generates an analog signal, which it then decodes and displays.

Answer (score 3):

UHF is just a frequency range and can carry anything. The format of the video itself is called composite video or CVBS (color, video, blanking, sync), of which PAL, NTSC etc are, so to speak, subformats. The signal a TV receives is some UHF carrier frequency which is frequency-modulated with the video and sound signals. UHF carries many TV stations and the first thing a TV does is to tune in on a particular channel to isolate the video signal which it then feeds to its PAL or NTSC decoding circuitry which in turn generates signals that drive the CRT.

With that said, I think what one would have to do is to arm oneself with a TV's block diagram (like this one http://smendes.com/el31l/blockdiagram.jpg .) and write a software emulation for each of the boxes:) (except the CRT stuff, of course.) "Luckily", underneath it's all "just" maths and most parts lend themselves to a nice mathematical description, involving lots of differential equations (I think this is how electronics are designed in the first place, i.e. before being prototyped and/or mass produced. Each branch of electronics (say, acoustics, filter design, amplifier design and whatnot) has some sort of mathematical apparatus associated with it.) In the end, your program will parse PAL as does an analog TV, the analog computer that it is))
You could also take a look at SDR, which stands for "software defined radio" which I think is the same principle.

Comment: This is nice. My question is: do you think I will be able to tackle the frequency range with a 4-core, one of the comments above suggest I cannot do that.

Comment: I don't know... The video signal's bandwidth is about 6MHz. Suppose you wanted to convert that to digital. You'd sample it at twice the maximum frequency and with an appropriate bitness (not sure, but let's assume 16 bit.) Multiply that and you get the data rate you would be dealing with (192 Mbit/s). A modern computer can deal with that at least throughput-wise, whether one can generate and decode PAL on the fly would depend on how much calculation is involved.

Comment: As to UHF, (non-cable) TV channels reside at about 470-862 MHz. That's difficult even in terms of throughput. So, I'd say, video is definitely possible, UHF probably not.